# Can't convert a dataframe into a dictionary for viewing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am a newby and I'm trying to convert this text file with 2 columns (about 160,000 records) into a dictionary so when 1 ID is searched for, it displays all the 5 corresponding descriptions along with it. I tried doing this with just the dataframe but it prints all records, and that too 5 times. Also some of the IDs are shorter than others and for those it gives an error. I was told to convert it to a dictionary but I've been trying to learn about dictionaries and cant seem to understand all the elements in it like keys and what not.

Image_ID    Description

- 1000092795.jpg#0 Two young guys with shaggy hair look at their hands while hanging out in the yard
- 1000092795.jpg#1 Two young , White males are outside near many bushes
- 1000092795.jpg#2 Two men in green shirts are standing in a yard
- 1000092795.jpg#3 A man in a blue shirt standing in a garden
- 1000092795.jpg#4 Two friends enjoy time spent together
- 10002456.jpg#0   Several men in hard hats are operating a giant pulley system
- 10002456.jpg#1   Workers look down from up above on a piece of equipment
- 10002456.jpg#2   Two men working on a machine wearing hard hats
- 10002456.jpg#3   Four men on top of a tall structure
- 10002456.jpg#4   Three men on a large rig
- 1000268201.jpg#0 A child in a pink dress is climbing up a set of stairs in an entry way
- 1000268201.jpg#1 A little girl in a pink dress going into a wooden cabin
- 1000268201.jpg#2 A little girl climbing the stairs to her playhouse
- 1000268201.jpg#3 A little girl climbing into a wooden playhouse
- 1000268201.jpg#4 A girl going into a wooden building
- 1000344755.jpg#0 Someone in a blue shirt and hat is standing on stair and leaning against a window
- 1000344755.jpg#1 A man in a blue shirt is standing on a ladder cleaning a window
- 1000344755.jpg#2 A man on a ladder cleans the window of a tall building
- 1000344755.jpg#3 man in blue shirt and jeans on ladder cleaning windows
- 1000344755.jpg#4 a man on a ladder cleans a window

(Here is a chunk of data to gain better understanding)
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfaLB.png)
This is an example of the data I am dealing with. Each ID has 5 jpgs and descriptions attached to it. I want it so when the ID is entered once, all 5 corresponding descriptions are printed. My current code is also attached here.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('results.txt', delimiter="\t")
#print(df)
imageid = input('Enter the ID: ')
for i in range(5):
    imageid_combined = imageid+'.jpg#'+str(i)
    print(df['Description'].where(df['Image_ID'] == 
str(imageid_combined)))
```

Comment: Please edit your question and put the data and code in text form (so we can copy-paste it).

Comment: Apologies, its edited now

Comment: Can you add the data in text form too?

Comment: I have added a small chunk of the data for better understanding of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b})

df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

This will output:

```
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['e'], 4: ['f'], 6: ['g']}
```